# Trouble to fetch data from an object in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I have an angular controller which returns an object from which I need to show data using ng-repeat in ionic framwork. But I am facing issues while doing so.
Below is my controller.js file.

```
.controller('CardCtrl', function($scope) {

var Cards = Parse.Object.extend("cards");
var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var query = new Parse.Query(Cards);
query.equalTo("mobile", XXXXXXXXX);
query.equalTo("status", true);
query.find({

  success: function(results) {
       $(".success").show();


  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
      var object = results[i];
      var id = object.id;
      var expiry = object.get('cardExpiry').toString();
      var number = object.get('cardNumber').toString();


        //checks for card type          
        if(number.substr(0,1) === '4')
        {
          var cardType = 'Visa';
        }
       else if(number.substr(0,1) === '5')
       {
        var cardType = 'Master';
       }
      $scope.cards = object;
      console.log($scope.cards);
    }

      },
      error: function(model, error) {
        $(".error").show();
      }
    });
```

This is my code for ionic.

```
<div class="card">
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="card in cards" href="#/app/cards/{{card.id}}">
  {{card.cardExpiry}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</div>
```

I am attaching the screenshot(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAHna.png) of the page I am getting. Those blank lists are coming because of the elements in the object (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWo8z.png) I suppose.

Again, the values I am fetching is repeating. It should be 102017 and 102018 respectively nut 102018 twice. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: this may be wrong but try
    <ion-item ng-repeat="card in cards" href="#/app/cards/card.id">     i have run into problems including the angular templating {{}} inside the <> tags

Comment: No, it didn't help. Still the same problem. I guesss I am lost in retrieving the data from the object properly. I see there's an **attributes** object inside. I am not able to figure how to define my scope.

Comment: You are logging $scope.cards. It would be helpful to see this. To see if the cards collection contain the correct data to start with?

Comment: I don't believe you're populating your `$scope.cards` correctly.  You are looping through your object array overriding the value of `$scope.cards` on every iteration.  I think you would be best off doing `$scope.cards.push(object)` which will push the object element to the end rather than replacing.  You should also declare `$scope.cards = [];` outside the loop.